# Is there a way to view my current equipment from the Auction House?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know that you can compare a potential item for sale with the corresponding item on your character by hovering on the house item's icon, but is there a way to "review" what you've currently got equipped as a whole? I mean, before actually performing a specific search?

I'm thinking that it'll be mighty useful when you try to go to the AH to ramp up your gear and can't recall what you're buying for OR if you're looking out for quick ramp ups (like if, for example, I've just logged in) . I find that not every time I go there I already know what I want to get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go to the SELL tab on the auction house and check the stats of all your items.

Comment: aaaaaaaaand I just had one of those `why didn't I think of that` moments. Thanks!

Comment: Also notice the list on right to toggle between characters, it isn't limited to the last active char.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the sell tab in the Auction house, you can select a character, and see the items you have equipped.  The downside is that it only shows items at full durability.

Otherwise you can do a search for any item in that particular slot, and the mouse over will compare the item on your selected character.

Answer (score 0):

You can view your equip in the menus by clicking on your character profile then chose the right character and click inspect. There is no way to get the same inferface in the auction house but I think it's better than having to relog to see the characters equipment.